# iOS 7.1 UINavigationbar and UIToolbar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar, uicolor, ios7.1

After upgrading Xcode in iOS7.1 my navigation bar and `UIToolbar` buttons are not shown with correct colour.

When a view first appears the `UIToolbar` buttons all have the correct default blue colour and when I go to next page/view and come back to the previous view the toolbar buttons are shown in a grey colour.

I have tried to add the blue colour in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` but no luck. Can someone please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a theme for certain components all at once and they will be used throughout your application. In my app delegate I created a function when the application is initializing called setupTheme, and it does just that - sets up the "theme" of the application by saying things like [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:], which in effect sets the color of the navigation bar for ANY navigation controller throughout the app. Here's an example from an app that sets up some basic components that are reused so that any time you use them they will already have the correct theme applied.

```
- (void)setupTheme {
    // get our theme colors
    UIColor *primaryThemeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    UIColor *secondaryThemeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // nav bar
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:primaryThemeColor];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:secondaryThemeColor];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:secondaryThemeColor}];

    // tab bar
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:primaryThemeColor];

    // switches
    [[UISwitch appearance] setOnTintColor:primaryThemeColor];

    // search bar
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Check out the iOS 7 transition guide for more details on specifics https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW1